# Extract frequency component from function

Tags: fft, numerical-methods, numerical

I have some arbitrary function, `f(x)`, that has no period.  I wish to find the magnitude of 1 frequency component in `f(x)`.  Could someone please recommend a fast way to do this?

So far, my ideas involve:

1. Taking the inner product of `f(x)` with the desired frequency e.g.
   `<f(x),cos(kx)>`.  This would essentially be finding the Fourier Coefficient at a given frequency.  To find the fourier coeffieicients, I am meant to do it over one period; however, since the period is large, I suppose I would just do it over less than one period and hope that it's accurate enough...
2. Doing an FFT of the signal, and then simply finding the frequency
   component I want from the FFT.
3. Somehow perhaps doing something with a narrow band-pass filter.

Edit:
Thank you for the suggestion.

I found the [following](https://github.com/nickponline/snippets/blob/master/goertzel-algorithm.py) algorithm written in Python (which is what I need) and slightly adjusted it to suit.

```
def Goetrzel(x, target_frequency, sample_rate):
    s_prev = 0
    s_prev2 = 0
    normalized_frequency = target_frequency / sample_rate

    wr = np.cos(2.0 * np.pi * normalized_frequency)
    wi = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * normalized_frequency)

    coeff = 2.0 * wr
    for sample in x:
        s = sample + coeff * s_prev - s_prev2
        s_prev2 = s_prev
        s_prev = s

    XKreal = s_prev * wr - s_prev2
    XKimag = s_prev * wi

    XK = (XKreal + 1j*XKimag) / (len(x)/2.)

    #power = s_prev2 * s_prev2 + s_prev * s_prev - coeff * s_prev * s_prev2 ;
    return abs(XK), np.angle(XK)*180./PI
```

I test it with:

```
h = 0.01
z = np.arange(0., 300., h)
f = np.cos(2.*PI*3.*z)
print Goetrzel(f, 3., 1./h)
```

If I make `h = 0.0007`, the answer calculated by the Goetrzel algorithm seems to significantly change (increases massively).  Do you have any idea why, or how I can make sure I pick the correct step?

So changing `h` from `0.06` to `0.07` changes the phase from `-1.388e-11°` to `21.6°`.

Comment: If you are interested in just the power at a known frequency, you could look at the Lomb periodogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explore the [Görtzel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) algorithm. It was designed to detect the presence of one or few (16) frequency components in a signal.